# An id conforming to the protocol vs Qualify an id with a protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, methods, protocols

I was going through [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW3) document provided by Apple.

I'm trying to understand the following paragraph, but so far, unable to do so.

```
@protocol XYZPieChartViewDataSource
- (NSUInteger)numberOfSegments;
- (CGFloat)sizeOfSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;
@optional
- (NSString *)titleForSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;
@required
- (UIColor *)colorForSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segmentIndex;
@end

@interface XYZPieCharView : UIView
@property (weak) id <XYZPieChartViewDataSource> dataSource;
// some additional stuff
@end
```

> If you attempt to call the respondsToSelector: method on an id
>   conforming to the protocol as it’s defined above, you’ll get a
>   compiler error that there’s no known instance method for it. Once you
>   qualify an id with a protocol, all static type-checking comes back;
>   you’ll get an error if you try to call any method that isn’t defined
>   in the specified protocol. One way to avoid the compiler error is to
>   set the custom protocol to adopt the NSObject protocol.

I'm getting confused at what is the difference between "Conforming to the protocol" and "Qualify some object with Protocol". And why should compiler generate an error if we send an id - that conforms to the protocol - the `respondsToSelector` message?

Comment: With the many many protocols datasources delegates I have implemented so far, I cannot tell exactly what the sentence wants to explain. Yet, I am using protocols no problem. In my personal humble opinion, I think you go to implement it in real case and see how it works and feel when you need a protocol is the fastest way to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> And why should compiler generate an error if we send an id - that conforms to the protocol - the respondsToSelector message

Yes, this is a very odd thing. Nowadays, under ARC, the compiler will throw an error if an object declared as `id <XYZPieChartViewDataSource>` is sent the `respondsToSelector:` method, the `class` method, or any other familiar basic NSObject instance method! Try it and see.

This seems strange, because `id` should permit any (known) message to be sent to it. However, `id <XYZPieChartViewDataSource>` is considered a completely specific type; the compiler will allow *only* messages that are part of the XYZPieChartViewDataSource protocol. One modern solution is this: don't use

```
id <XYZPieChartViewDataSource>
```

Instead, use

```
NSObject<XYZPieChartViewDataSource>*
```

This causes all the yummy goodness of NSObject to be included (as far as the compiler is concerned) in this object, including the ability to respond to `respondsToSelector:` and `class` and things like that.

Here's a paragraph I've inserted in my book, discussing this very issue:

> Curiously, the compiler treats an object typed as `id<SomeProtocol>` very differently from how it treats an object typed as `id`, allowing only methods defined in SomeProtocol to be sent to that object. For example, suppose MyClass is defined with a `delegate` property typed as `id<MyProtocol>`. Then if `obj` is a MyClass instance, you can't speak of `[obj.delegate class]`; the compiler complains that `class` is not a known instance method! That's because `obj.delegate` is typed as `id<MyProtocol>`, and thus its *only* known instance method is `doSomething:`, the method defined by MyProtocol. We can work around this by casting `obj.delegate` to an `id`; a more elegant solution, when the definition of MyClass is up to us, is to declare the `delegate` property as `NSObject<MyProtocol>*` instead of `id<MyProtocol>`.

Comment: Having your protocol extend `< NSObject >` means the object you get at runtime could be an `NSProxy`, and specifying the protocol is more restrictive than specifying the class type (usually considered good practice). So what is the merit of specifying the class as `NSObject` with a protocol? Personal preference or I'm missing something?

Comment: @Wain Having the protocol specify that it conforms to `<NSObject>` protocol would do also. I've never used NSProxy so in practice the distinction never arises for me. Plus, I got the `NSObject<...>*` idea direct from Greg Parker at Apple and I tend to just go with what he says! :) I've edited my answer a bit.

Comment: Surely this is not really "Curiously" at all, though the syntax may be somewhat confusing at first glance. Declaring a variable to be of a class type is asserting that the reference object provides the methods etc. of the class, it does not assert anything else. Declaring a variable to be of a protocol type should be a direct parallel of this (as is also the case in Java). Nothing curious here. The only issue is syntax. As protocols occur in <> brackets after a class in the syntax, what to use to mean "just the protocol", `id` makes sense as "anything and the protocol" is a redundant spec.

Comment: @CRD Well, different people are surprised at different things. All I can tell you is, the first time I said `respondsToSelector:` to a reference typed as `id<SomeProtocol>` and the compiler barfed at me, I was very surprised!

Comment: @matt - We are indeed :-) However I suggest the issue you face is more to do with protocols not including the NSObject protocol by default than the syntax for "protocol typed variable". Few Obj-C programmers would miss out the NSObject base on an interface (and are surprised by the errors when they do), but how many miss it out on a protocol? Java doesn't have the same issue as there is only one root object so everything must implement its methods regardless. Of course missing out NSObject on the protocol allows the protocol to be implemented by classes with other roots... Isn't Obj-C fun :)

Comment: @matt I purchased your book and further looking to purchase the next book: "Programming iOS 7". Hope I go well with it.

Answer (score 4):

> Conforming to the protocol

This is when you `@interface` definition for your class specifies that the class implements (or conforms to) a protocol. This is information to the compiler to verify that the class does indeed implement the required methods.

```
@interface MyClass < MyProtocol >
```

> Qualify some object with Protocol

This is adding extra information to a pointer type, usually an `id`, to tell the compiler that the object it references will implement the methods specified by the protocol (so they are valid to be called). The inverse of this is that any methods that aren't defined in the protocol are not valid to be called and you'll get a warning if you try.

```
id < MyProtocol > myObject = ...;
```