# What is the difference between sending selector to id with and without protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, clang

How could that be?

**Compile error:**

```
id<NSCoding> response = [[NSObject alloc] init];
id copy = [response copy];
```

**Compilation success:**

```
id response = [[NSObject alloc] init];
id copy = [response copy];
```

**Compilation success:**

```
id<NSCoding> response = [[NSObject alloc] init];
id copy = [((id)response) copy];
```

---

```
$clang --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

*P.S. Code has only presentation purpose and will raise `NSInvalidArgumentException`.*

Comment: Do you mean `NSCopying`?

Comment: @bsarr007, no, I didn't. You can change protocol and selector to any other.

Comment: Use `NSObject < NSCoding > *response ...`

Comment: @Wain, you can change NSObject, NSCoding and copy to ANY values you like

Comment: By narrowing the type of id to id<NSCoding> you are restricting the compiler's knowledge of what methods response responds to to just those in NSCoding.  Since copy is part of NSCopying and not part of NSCoding, it's a compile time error.  By typecasting back to id, you are telling the compiler that I don't know what this is, but it responds to anything and everything.  Ie., any message can be sent to an object of type id.

Comment: I don't follow your comment. The order and meaning of my comment is important...

Comment: @David I don't think changing id to id<SomeProto> will narrow type. It's just promise about some messages object will respond to, it has nothing to do with type power/cardinality (I don't remeber how this property of type called). Am I right?

Comment: @folex my guess as to the logic is that since you could send any method to an object of type id, that the compiler assumes that since you're specifically saying it has the protocol SomeProto, that that's the only thing you're going to do with it.  Otherwise, why bother with they protocol specification.  But, that's just supposition based on observed compiler behavior.

Comment: @David, well, I think that's just a bug in compiler.

Comment: btw, if you want to use both coding and copying at the same time, I believe you can use `id<NSCoding, NSCopying> response;`

Comment: I suppose you can make the argument, but it's pretty irrelevant since Apple is both the definition and implementation of the language :)  See gnasher's answer for yet more rationale for the behavior.

Comment: @David, it's not about NSCopying or NSCoding, you can replace them by any other protocol. I've used NSCoding so anyone could test that behaviour on their own. I even left P.S., but it doesn't seem to work :)

Comment: See much more discussion here [An id conforming to the protocol vs Qualify an id with a protocol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794634/an-id-conforming-to-the-protocol-vs-qualify-an-id-with-a-protocol)

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a variable of type `id<SomeProtcol>`, the compiler assumes you will only call methods from the protocol. `copy` is not a method of the `NSCoding` protocol.

Of course if the variable is just `id`, you can call any method available from any known class/protocol at the time.

Comment: Is this "feature" documented somewhere?

Comment: Probably. The answer is based off of experience.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler uses whatever information it has to try to find out what method calls you can use. If a variable has just type "id" then the compiler knows nothing about the actual object, so whatever method you send to the object, the compiler has to trust you - except if you send a message that doesn't match any message that the compiler knows about. (The compiler could decide that because it cannot determine at compile time that any message is valid, it doesn't allow any messages, but that would make the type "id" quite useless).

If a variable has type id  then the compiler knows this object supports the protocol SomeProtocol but knows nothing else. Now the compiler assumes that if you knew more about the object, you would have told the compiler, for example by using the NSObject*  . Since you didn't, the compiler will allow *only* methods to be sent that belong to the protocol

Comment: Is it documented somewhere?