# What does it mean to "conform to protocol" in Objective-C/Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I came across a lot of "this thing conforms to that protocol" when working on tutorial iOS apps. What does this mean?

There are two types of this that I see:

1. Along the lines of `id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections] [section];`
2. By setting some delegate to self and then having to implement the delegate method or something similar to that.

What is the difference and why are we doing that?

Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22794742/5020627

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A protocol is a promise to implement certain methods. To conform to a protocol means that you both make that promise and fulfill it.

Your example of `id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>` is "any kind of object that implements the required methods of the protocol `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo`." (`id` in Objective-C means "any kind of object.")

Most `setDelegate:` methods require that the argument conform to some protocol. So before assigning yourself as a delegate, you need to make sure you add the promise (as part of your `@interface`) and implement the methods (to fulfill the promise).

Comment: For the `id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>` part I simply wrote that line and didn't have to implement any required methods of `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo`, it's like the part in <> was simply part of a variable definition.but by defining a self view controller as a delegate I had to set the class to both conform to the protocol AND implement the delegate method. This is why I'm confused.

Comment: `id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>` is the type of `sectionInfo`. It's not *your* type. So whatever object is returned by `[self.fetchedResultsController sections] [section]` has to conform to the protocol. Your view controller doesn't need to.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Objective-C allows you to define protocols, which declare the methods
>   expected to be used for a particular situation. This chapter describes
>   the syntax to define a formal protocol, and explains how to mark a
>   class interface as conforming to a protocol, which means that the
>   class must implement the required methods.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html